# django cant access mysql docker compose

Tags: mysql, django, docker-compose

this is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  djangoSql:
    restart: always
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: djangoSql
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test1
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
      - 6044:3306
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10


  web:
    build: .
    network_mode: bridge
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    image: django
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: djangoSql:3306
      WAIT_HOSTS_TIMEOUT: 300
      WAIT_SLEEP_INTERVAL: 30
      WAIT_HOST_CONNECT_TIMEOUT: 30
    depends_on:
      - djangoSql
    links:
      - djangoSql:mysql
```

this is my error

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, 'Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: /usr//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mariadb19/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory')

the url has two usr i don't know why

this is docker file

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD ./wait-for-it.sh /code/wait-for-it.sh
ADD . /code/
CMD ["/code/wait-for-it.sh", "djangoSql:3306", "-t", "6000", "--`","python","manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]`
```

and this is requirement.txt

```
Django>=2.0,<3.0
djangorestframework
mysqlclient
tensorflow==1.15
setuptools>=41.0.0
pandas
Keras
```

Comment: What is your django docker image based on?

Comment: this is my requirement.txt

Comment: Django>=2.0,<3.0
djangorestframework
mysqlclient
tensorflow==1.15
setuptools>=41.0.0
pandas
Keras

Comment: it is python3.7

Comment: this is my docker file

Comment: FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD ./wait-for-it.sh /code/wait-for-it.sh
ADD . /code/
CMD ["/code/wait-for-it.sh", "djangoSql:3306", "-t", "6000", "--","python","manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

Comment: Please update your question with this info

Comment: i updated the quition

Comment: https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/454#issuecomment-425510307 also on official image page https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql (scroll to "docker-compose" part)

Comment: thank you. it's working now

Answer (score 2):

according to [mysql official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) you need to add this command to your mysql service in the compose file:

```
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

and do not forget to create a new container of your mysql image after adding this command.